# (Materialize:) Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'tabIndex')

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, materialize

I just upgraded to Materialize 1.0.0 from 0.9, I replaced the files of materialize.min.js, Materialize.css and Materialize.min.css in my project but I am getting this error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'tabIndex')
at n.value (materialize.min.js:6:40751)
at new n (materialize.min.js:6:35734)
at Function.value (materialize.min.js:6:11812)
at Function.value (materialize.min.js:6:44091)
at jQuery.fn.<computed> [as dropdown] (materialize.min.js:6:13212)
at initialize (<anonymous_name>.js:481:23)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>
```